# get data from spotify api using implicit grant flow in vue

Tags: api, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, spotify

im new at vuejs and working with api
i wanna connect to spotify api using implicit grant flow
i redirect user to authorize page and get access token, then i set header using axios instance.

this block of code is in main.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
export const base = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1',
  header: {
      'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + store.state.accessToken,
  }
});
Vue.prototype.$http = base;
```

and this one is in one of my components that i try to get data from api

```
mounted() {
            this.$http.get('/artists/1vCWHaC5f2uS3yhpwWbIA6')
                .then(data => this.albums = data)
                .catch(e => this.error = e)
        }
```

but the server responds with 401 error and this message:
Error: Request failed with status code 401

so what do you think?

Comment: `401` (Unauthorized) implies your token is invalid in this case. Given that you're setting the global header in `main.js` (before you've received the access token), it's likely that your header contains an empty string for the `Authorization` header. Note that `store.state.accessToken` isn't reactive in the way you're using it.

Comment: @tony19
oh cool i didnt know that. im using Vuex to manage states. so this means i cant use Vuex to manage my access token right?
i import store using this line of code
`import { store } from './store/store'`

Comment: Well, you *can* still use Vuex, and have a reactive access token in state, but that's not the way to do it. I assume that's really the answer you're after :)

Comment: @tony19
yeah thanks for your answer, it was realy helpful :D